# "I need help uncle."

Tags: grammaticality

So I am playing a game with my two year old niece where I fall down and she comes to help me saying "I need help uncle" as in "I need to help my uncle".  The family discussion at the moment is whether "I need help uncle." is grammatically correct when used in this way.

Comment: "I need help uncle" would be, in adult speech, her asking you for help. But she's two, so we can let this one pass ;)

Comment: @DanBron - It's worth considering the difference between "Let's eat, Grandma" and "Let's eat Grandma".

Comment: My brother and I dismissed it as incorrect immediately, but the example "I need only help uncle" was given which  made it a little less clear.

Comment: There is ambiguity in this expression. But the context can determine and clear it. When the speaker is in a helpless condition, *I need help uncle* means the speaker is need of help from their uncle. Whereas, if *I need help uncle* was indented to mean *I need to help my uncle*, the speaker would say *I wish/want to help you, uncle*.